# Is specifying `asc` on an order by in MySQL unnecessary?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

My understanding is that

```
select ... order by column;
```

and

```
select ... order by column asc;
```

are functionally equivalent.

Is there any situation in which it would be **required** to use `asc`?

Comment: No. ASC is default. You can just leave it. It will be used automatically if not defined.

Answer (score 2):

MYSQL order by statement takes asc by default. if you want in descending order should specify desc

Comment: This is true in all databases, not only MySQL.

Comment: not necessary, talk of a non relational database which does not have a primary index, or the index is not iterative . So in a generic statement, you are true, but for a  closed form statement I'd like to specify which db one is discussing.

Comment: . . An ascending sort has been the default in pretty much every tool I have ever used, database or otherwise.